# How to implement POST requests in an HTTP server with Python Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, http, server, python-requests

I'm making a local HTTP server for web design in Python with sockets and I've already implemented handling GET requests but I'm not sure how to implement POST requests. Can someone help me out?

**What I've tried:**

- Searching online for other solutions
- Looking into how other servers handle POST requests

**Expectations:**

- Handling basic POST requests like a file upload or a form submission

This is the block of code where I handle incoming requets:

```py
    def handle_client(self, conn, addr):
        BUFSIZ = 8192
 
        while True:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(BUFSIZ).decode()
 
                if data:
                    lines = data.split('\r\n')
 
                    req_line = lines[0]
 
                    req_method = req_line.split(' ')[0]
 
                    if req_method == 'GET':
                        response_line = b""
                        response_header = b""
                        blank_line = b"\r\n"
                        response_body = b""
 
 
                        requested_file = req_line.split(' ')[1]
 
                        if requested_file == '/':
                            requested_file = '/index.html'
                        else:
                            pass
 
                        filepath = self.content_dir + requested_file
 
                        print(f'Initiating webpage {filepath}')
 
                        try:
                            with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
                                response_body = f.read()
 
                            response_line = self.create_response_line(status_code=200)
                            response_header = self.create_headers()
                                        
                        
                        except Exception as e:
                            print(f'Something went wrong while trying to serve {filepath}')
 
                            response_line = self.create_response_line(status_code=404)
                            response_header = self.create_headers()
                            response_body = "<h1>{} {}</h1>".format(
                                404,
                                self.status_codes[404]
                            ).encode('utf8')
 
                        response = b""
 
                        response += response_line
                        response += response_header
                        response += blank_line
                        response += response_body
 
                        conn.send(response)
 
                        conn.close()
 
                        break
                    else:
                        print(f'Unsupported request method: {req_method}')
                
                else: break
            
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.sv.shutdown()
```

And this is the whole script: https://pastebin.com/8ievdfay

Comment: Okay, what are you having trouble with? Looks like you haven't implemented any POST handling at all. (Also, are you doing this all by hand just for exercise?)

Comment: I haven't implemented any handling at all because I'm not sure where exactly to start (i understand how post requests work and the difference between post and get) but i don't know what to do with the request body after i parse it. 

and yes i'm doing this all in raw sockets for learning/practice purposes

Comment: Well, if you know the request is a POST request, then after the `\r\n\r\n` after the request lines, you'll get some data in the format prescribed by the `Content-Type` and `Content-Encoding` headers.

Comment: yep, i understand that but what do i _actually do_ with the respective data? @AKX

Comment: for example if its an image upload, and the image is required by an html file, how do i give the data to the html file

Comment: If it's an image upload from a HTML form, the form needs to be `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`, and you'd get exactly that as your `Content-type`. Then you'd have to parse the data (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388) and finally process it however is appropriate (e.g. save the image onto disk).

Comment: hm... ok I'll try to go on from here. thanks for the help